# asp.net mvc AMP project don't work

Tags: asp.net, amp-html

My page code:

```
    @{ 
    Layout = null;
}
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
        "@@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
        "logo.jpg"
        ]
        }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
    <noscript>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
        body {
            -webkit-animation: none;
            -moz-animation: none;
            -ms-animation: none;
            animation: none
        }
    </style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the mobile web</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I copy and paste from AMP project web site but why don't work?
I get **"The mandatory text (CDATA) inside tag 'noscript > style[amp-boilerplate]' is missing or incorrect."** error.
My amp page url : **http://www.saharezervasyon.com/amp#development=1** with development query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes in this part

```
<style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style>
```

no blank space after body and before none

For more detail [**please visit this link**](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-boilerplate.md)